# How to add rows for each date?

Tags: sql-server, join

I am working on SQL Server.

I have a table with Names of people and a second table with dates.

How do I create a third table so that each name has all the corresponding dates?

Table1:

```
Name

Sam
Michael
Tom
Jerry
```

Table2:

```
Date

1/05/2014
3/06/2014
```

Table3

```
Name                 Date

Sam                1/05/2014
Sam                3/06/2014
Michael            1/05/2014
Michael            3/06/2014
Tom                1/05/2014
Tom                3/06/2014
Jerry              1/05/2014
Jerry              3/06/2014
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a cross join:

```
SELECT * FROM Name, Date
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Name
CROSS JOIN Date
```

Comment: This will create the right data set. If you need it to be inserted into a new table, just place CREATE TABLE name_dates AS... in front of the query.

Comment: If table already exists, use INSERT INTO SELECT FROM. CREATE TABLE AS SELECT does not work for SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Using Cross Join

```
SELECT * FROM Name, Date
```